# pip is unable to find the version on github

Tags: pip

I see the version is [available](https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/releases) in the github, but pip is not be able to find it

Python 3.9.1
pip 21.2.4

**Question:**
How to install version djangorestframework-simplejwt 4.4.0?

```
 pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.4.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.4.0 (from versions: 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 
1.3, 1.4, 1.5.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.1, 3.0, 3.1, 
3.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.3, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.1.4, 
4.1.5, 4.2.0, 4.3.0, 4.5.0, 4.6.0, 4.7.0, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8.0)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.4.0
```

Comment: This worked for me with python 3.8 and pip 20.2. Did you try the installation with other version of python?

Comment: Haven't tried yet. Thank you for your response. I will update my status when I tried your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-simplejwt/4.4.0/

Requires: Python >=3.6, **<3.9**

Doesn't work with Python 3.9. Either downgrade Python or use a later version of `djangorestframework-simplejwt`. Starting with version [4.5](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-simplejwt/4.5.0/):

Requires: Python >=3.7